# Java heap space error while running hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, heap-memory

Every time I try to run a **hadoop** jar , I'm getting **Java heap space error**.
I have installed **hadoop-1.2.1** in my VMware.

This is my **conf/mapred-site.xml**:

```xml
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx1024m</value>
</property>
```

I have also added the following to **hadoop-env.sh**:

```sh
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx1024m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
```

Even after, each time I run the job it shows Java heap space exception and the job fails. Could some one help me out. Whenever I run my mapreduce my Linux becomes very slow. Too slow that it takes long even to open a browser.

Comment: Did you try to use a value that is bigger than 1024?

Comment: How big is your data? If you provide less memory for your application then the mapred job will not work properly.

Comment: 1. How much memory do you have? 2. Is it a 32 or 64-bit Linux system? 3. Have you tried a profiler such as VisualVM to find out which structures take up most of the used memory?

Comment: i am trying to run hadoop-examples.jar-1.2.1 from hadoop examples. I am using 64 -bit Linux system. No i have not tried that. The memory i set up for the virtual machine is IGB.

Comment: i dont know why the entire system is slow while running mapreduce

Comment: VM with hadoop atleast require 4 Gb of RAM,Increase memory of your Vm may solve your issue and if not then go for -Xms1g. But I think increasing memory for your VM will work.

Comment: my VM has 8 GB ram and utilizes like 6 GB when running a job. Your problem is high memory consumption as 1024 MB is used for both OS as well as map-reduce

Comment: thank you so much. Increased my VM ram to & GB . Now hadoop as well as hbaseruns fast and my system doesnt hang.